# drupal persistent login, why use?

Tags: drupal, authentication, persistent

Why do i have to use some `persistent-login` module to make my users login into Drupal 6
for longer period of time.

Why changing php.ini or settings.php doesnt works ?

from a "webtools" I see my cookies being expired in next day, but after few hours it happend to log me out.
This is like spontagenious action, no pattern to follow / predict.

why this "keep-alive" login exists in drupal ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not *have to* use the persistent module to achieve longer log in periods. You can simply adjust the `ini_set()` calls for the `session.*` PHP settings in your Drupal instances `settings.php` file (especially `session.cookie_lifetime` and `session.gc_maxlifetime`).

If adjusting those does not work for you, you should ensure that your server configuration allows overriding them from PHP.
Also, Drupal uses the standard PHP session storage mechanisms - if there are other PHP apps running on the same server, they might interfere with your session lifetime settings, depending on storage path configurations. See [point 2 in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1494403/php-pear-auth-session-timeout/1494641#1494641) for information on that.

The persistent login module aims to make the configuration easier, but especially adds more features, as e.g. allowing a general remember me option while still requiring reauthentication for sensitive operations (like changing the password) to minimize the risks associated with long login periods.

Check this [article linked from the modules project page](http://jaspan.com/improved_persistent_login_cookie_best_practice), as well as this [article linked from there](http://fishbowl.pastiche.org/2004/01/19/persistent_login_cookie_best_practice/) for some in depth explanations concerning the handling of persistent logins.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal overrides the internal php session save handler in include/bootstrap.ini and has some non standard session code there.  Haven't followed it through though.

Beyond that Drupal's settings.php will override php.ini.